# PHP Pear Mail on reception

Tags: php, email, pear

I would like to know if there's any way I can send a **automatic** answer to client when I open them mail who's comming from my website ?

Anybody have sugestion ?

> Has asked here is more information:
>
> I Have a online cart who send me a
> e-mail when I receive order, I would
> like that when I open the order
> there's a email automaticly been sent
> to the client to tell him that i've
> took his order. Like when you open a
> e-mail and that tell you that the
> sender asked to receive a confirmation
> that you've received the mail.
>
> For resume I would like that when I receive a order mail, and open it there anoter email who's sent directly to the client telling him that i've openned his order and processing it.

Comment: confusing question, try to write more to let us help you properly.

Comment: I agree, your question is a bit unclear, I hope you can use my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a script on your website, for example 'mysite.com/confirmread.php'. In this script you can write code to send an e-mail to the customer.
Then, in the e-mail that is sent to you on the customer's order, you can create a link towards this script. You can click the link then, for example: 'mysite.com/confirmread.php?ordernr=2883992' or 'mysite.com/confirmread.php?mail=customer@domain.com'.

Another way might be an automatic script that is fired once you open your e-mail. I'm thinking of a javascript / ajax script, which calls the same script (confirmread.php), but without you having to click the link. I'm not sure to which extent scripting is supported in e-mail clients (think of the difference between online vs offline mail clients).

You can, of course, also reply the e-mail to another address of your own. For example sale@mysite.com. This address can then be read by the PHP script. But I guess that's more complex.

Comment: Thanks ! I Will search in that way ! But I don't think that e-mail client support ajax ! I will take a look at this and post a complete solution after, maybe that could help someone else after ! Thanks for your replie !

Answer (score 1):

You have to hook into the IMAP server and check the status of the emails periodically. And when on changes its status from unread to read you can send an email. But this means you have to track the status of the emails in a separate database against this DB you have to check then if the email was already read.

Better solution:
Add into your order mail a link at the bottom which links to a script which sends an email to the customer. So, you have to manually trigger this email but its very easy to implement.

**Example in pseudo code:**

**Link at the bottom of the order email:**

```
yourserver.com/sendEmailThatOrderWasReceived.php?orderid=123&customerEmail=test@example.com
```

**Script on your server:**

```
<?php 
mail($_REQUEST['customerEmail'], 'Order '.$_REQUEST['oderId'].' is confirmed', 'Thank you for your order, we had a look at it.');
```